# 3d supersymmetric theory

Tags: field-theory, representation-theory, supersymmetry

I just started studying supersymmetry and for a project I need to understand the vector multiplet field content of a 3d ${\cal N}=4$ theory in terms of 3d ${\cal N}=2$ multiplets.

I tried approaching the problem as in 4d theories by trying to construct massless representation via the induced representation but I got stuck without finding a little group that makes me define helicity and therefore labelling the multiplets.

I have read it is possible to obtain 3d multiplet via dimensional reduction of 4d theories but I did not understand how to, could you please explain how to?